# Using jQuery tokeninput and text together

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-select2, jquery-tokeninput

I want the user to give me a long string value in a TextBox in my ASP.NET MVC application. In the string, if the user enters a word that I already have in my system, I want to display it with a jQuery token.

This is better explained with an example:

Let's say the phrase user is entering is "I drink coffee every morning except Sunday mornings." In this example, let's say I already have the words "coffee" and "Sunday" in my database with their respective ID's e.g. coffee Id: 123 and "Sunday" Id: 7789

What I'm trying to do is that as the user types the phrase, I want to automatically replace the words "coffee" and "Sunday" with their jQuery inputtokens. The idea is that I identify each word with its own ID if possible i.e. coffee is 123 and Sunday is 7789.

So when I save this phrase in my system, I may store it as "I drink [Id:123] every morning except [Id:7789] mornings". However, the user sees the phrase as he/she entered it except the familiar words are represented as jQuery tokens.

I could use some help in creating this behavior.

Comment: use jquery plugin for token input and save all keyword's json in local-storage for quick response

Comment: The problem is mixing tokens with text. I've never seen tokens and regular text mixed together i.e. word1 [token1] word2 word 3 [token2]

Comment: so do something which you seen at some other websites. Otherwise it will confuse and disturb users. You can also parse the whole string at server to separate out the words which you have in database.

Answer (score 1):

This would be possible using [jQuery TokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/). (Download the latest version from Github for freetagging functionality, rather than the old 1.6.0 from the website.)

I did something similar for a text translation based project, where phrases which weren't found in the dictionary were shown differently. Instead of having 'tokens' and 'non-tokens', everything will be a token, just some tokens can be styled through adding a CSS class to look like normal text.

With TokenInput, make sure you set `allowFreeTagging:true` to be allowed to enter non-dictionary words. I'd imagine you'd want <kbd>space</kbd> to 'submit' a tag, and treat each word individually. Then make use of the `onFreeTaggingAdd()` call back to add a new css class to those tags which are not in your dictionary. The CSS would simply be a matter of removing all the borders, background-colour and padding which are put round the text to make it look like a 'number'. I believe you should also be able to get rid of the delete button on each token, either through the options, of with a simple modification to the codebase.